# Is there a module equivalent for Suggest a Friend for Drupal 7?

Tags: 7

I am creating a social networking site for which I need the [Suggest a Friend](http://drupal.org/project/suggest-a-friend) module, but it is not available for Drupal 7. Is there a similar module for Drupal 7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very powerful social networking module for creating inner social network for Drupal 7 is [User Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationships).

It is well supported so i guess you can accomplish what you need.

Comment: one thing more! I want to show all users in one page. by this module can i have users or should i use another module?

Comment: If you use views module, you can use it to display all users. (and also use pager to break large listings).